# Determining WordPress User Session ID and Returning Current User Email Address

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, session

I am a newbie and excited I have my code working with php and mysql. I want to have a Word Press website page where users can view their account info such as profile name and the email they registered with. However, my code just returned all emails and display names. So I need to add something to the SELECT statement in the code below such as WHERE user_login ='".$_SESSION['id']."'

The problem is, I know nothing about how to start a session ID for a user that logs in (does this happen automatically with Word Press?) and then I have no idea how to correctly write the SELECT statement that determines who the user is so that it returns just that user's registered email and chosen alternative display name. Also, where on earth would a session ID declaration go in WordPress (in the index.php at the very top?)

This is what I have so far (the code that just returns all records and not just the current user info):

```
 mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("i541280_wp1") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_users") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 Print "Display Name:".$info['display_name']; 
 Print "Email:".$info['user_email']; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dond't know if this is what you want, but i'll try. Make a commmet if isn't it what you want.

This code return the email adress of the current logged user.

```
<?php
    $logged_user = wp_get_current_user(); // Get current user info
    echo $logged_user->user_email; // Return the email of the current user
?>
```

More information here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

Comment: I did see that code somewhere and just wanted to be sure there was no need for sessions before I build my tables (the site will need to keep track of user activity and award points for various activities). Given this, do you think sessions really aren't necessary for such a WordPress site? Do some major membership websites with membership sites that award points for things get by without sessions?

Comment: I think the sessions aren't necessary. You can manipulate all the user activity without use sessions. Use transients and options are good ways for that. Transients are temporary values and options are permanent values. With this guys, you can do many things to track the activity of the users.

Comment: Very good, thanks. And this code did the trick for what I need so far. Thanks!